# How to display two children in one row and third child in 2nd row

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to display User ID and the check mark in top row and the text box in 2nd row using flex. I'm unable to do this, so any help is greatly appreciated.

This is what I'm getting:

[image: My display]

```
<body>        
  <div style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; width:100%;">
       <div>User ID</div>
       <img style="margin-right:3px; align-self:center;" src="correct.png" /> 
       <div><input type="text" name="fname"></div> 
  </div>      
</body>
```

This is what I want:

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the HTML (move the close `</div>` of `flex` after the `<img>`)

```html
<div style="display:flex;">
       <div>User ID</div>
       <img style="margin-right:3px; align-self:center;" src="correct.png" /> 
</div>  
<div><input type="text" name="fname"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

i have put `user id` and `img` in 1 `div` and made it `flex`

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div style="display:flex; width:100%;">
      <div>User ID</div>
      <img style="margin-right:3px; align-self:center;" src="correct.png" />
    </div>
    <div><input type="text" name="fname"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```